# Hide another element when details[open]

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have a standard

```
<details>
<summary>
Text
</summary>
</details>
```

and a `<div class="something">` elsewhere on the same page (outside the `details` altogether). How to hide the `div` when `details[open]`, for example by setting `.something {display: none;}`?

I tried

```
details[open] > .something {
  display: none;
}
```

with and without the `>`, but it doesn't do anything.

I'm open to JS as well, but I'd expect this to work in css.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the sibling operator. But please not that the CSS cannot traverse up or reverse.

```css
details[open] ~ .nested .something,
details[open] + .something {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<details>
  <summary>Details</summary>
  Something small enough to escape casual notice.
</details>
<div class="something">Something something, open details.</div>
<div class="nested">
  <p>Let's try to target the below too.</p>
  <p class="something">You won't see this if details is open.</p>
</div>
```

TBH, this kinda explains it:

[image]